# Axis Bands of Rotation Gizmo Difficult to See

Tags: gizmo

When I have an object selected and switch to the Rotation Tool, the axis bands on the gizmo are so thin I can barely see them. Is there a way to increase the thickness of these lines? THX

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the line thickness in *Preferences > Interface*.
It affects most lines, including gizmos.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using blender 2.82 and unfortunately, this didn't make any difference. The lines are still super thin in the rotation gizmo.

Comment: @KBrumfield Weird, this is also 2.82. You can also increase the resolution scale, but that will affect the whole UI.

Comment: I'm also on a Mac. Would that make any difference?

Comment: No, it should be the same :). Try saving preferences and restarting blender, or you can help the developers by reporting it as a bug in *Help > Report a bug*

Comment: I submitted a bug report and received the following reply...  This is indeed a known issue on Mac, which uses more strict version of OpenGL. Marking as known issue, but even so this is quite problematic on Macs, especially since they all ship with retina displays, making the 1px lines extremely thin.

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer :). Thanks a lot for looking into it, would you mind posting it as an answer? I'm sure it will help other confused Mac users.

Comment: Will do. Still learning. THX

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a bug report and received the following reply... This is indeed a known issue on Mac, which uses more strict version of OpenGL. Marking as known issue, but even so this is quite problematic on Macs, especially since they all ship with retina displays, making the 1px lines extremely thin.