# Now to adjust the line thickness of the gizmo without changing other thicknesses?

Tags: python, gizmo

I would like to increase the thickness of the lines in the gizmo, since on some pc/monitor/mouse is really hard click on the 1 pixel lines to do something.

I know that there is the property for the size of gizmo but it doesn't change the thickness of lines, only how big are the circles and arrows.

Can this be done making a new gizmo with python?

I found this addon https://blendermarket.com/products/gizmo-pro-addon-blender-2
that make me wonder if is something doable.

I have seen the templates for gizmo but with only that I am really not able to go further, do you have any gizmo tutorial?

Thanks for your time.

[image: Gizmo and gizmo with extended lines.]

Comment: See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168358/axis-bands-of-rotation-gizmo-difficult-to-see) posting from a year ago.

Comment: Hi man , thanks for reply , 
yes setting can be set to thick to have the lines, like 2 pixels thick XD
and also we can set the " resolution scale " but that setting change the whole blender to unusable size...

with some settings is really hard to click on the lines and i usually mistake clicking on Trackball style rotation...  
if you have any more trick let me know 

Thank you very much for your time